# Two parts mysql query, order the results displaying the ones from the first part, first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql query.

Any ideas how to order the results in order to get the ones from the first part of the query first, followed by the ones from the second part of the query.

Here is how I do it, but it's not working properly, mixing results together.

```
SELECT name, pic0, bio,site
FROM ".$table."
WHERE ( (name LIKE '%john%' OR name LIKE '%smith%') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') )
   OR ( name IS NOT NULL AND category IN ('drivers', 'construction') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') )
ORDER BY ( (name LIKE '%john%' OR name LIKE '%smith%') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') ) DESC
LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$rowsperpage."");
```

Thank you

Comment: What you mean by first part and second part? Do you mean the WHERE OR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the query in two queries and `UNION` them

Union in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Your query should look something like this, although i haven't tested it:

```
(SELECT name, pic0, bio,site
FROM ".$table."
WHERE ( (name LIKE '%john%' OR name LIKE '%smith%') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') )
ORDER BY ( (name LIKE '%john%' OR name LIKE '%smith%') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') ) DESC)
UNION
(SELECT name, pic0, bio,site
FROM ".$table."
WHERE ( name IS NOT NULL AND category IN ('drivers', 'construction') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') )
ORDER BY ( (name LIKE '%john%' OR name LIKE '%smith%') AND site LIKE ('%site1%') ) DESC)
```

Comment: never worked with union before, could you please give me an example, I am somewhat of a nube and it would save me a few hours of trial and error. If u do not have time I understand.

Comment: If you got two queries that return the same columns you can "output" the two results of the two queries as one result. Example: `(SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = 1000) UNION (SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL2 = 1110)`

Comment: Ty very much, this is really interesting. But what about duplicate rows? For example the bio of a driver named john which will display in the first query but also in the second.

Comment: @webmasters: `UNION` will remove all duplicates, `UNION ALL` would be used to preserve them.

Comment: From the docs link i posted in my answer: *The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result*.

Answer (score 0):

If by *first part of the query* you mean the first `WHERE`-condition, it should be sufficient to add a `DESC` after your existing `ORDER BY`-clause.

Since it uses the same logic as you have as first condition, it will be `1` for those rows where the first condition is true, and `0` for the rest.

Sorting in descending order should put the results from the first condition first.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I have a DESC. Ty very much

Comment: Sorry, got confused by your query formatting (fixed it now). Your query should actually work then, here is a [simple example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85575/1) I put together with SQL Fiddle...

Comment: It works partially, for example I have 18 nickname which contain the word john (john smith, john adams) followed by 2 which don't and followed by more which contain them. Weird

Comment: Guess that those two meet one of the other conditions (`smith` or `site1`)?

Comment: No tested this with only 1 condition